# SQL count value returning 0 even though room is not allocated

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with my SQL query again...

D.0.02 has been allocated for day 1 period 1 so it should count 0. But it has not been allocated for day 1 period 2. Why is it returning as 0?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rm.Id)
FROM ts_room rm LEFT JOIN ts_roompref rp ON rp.room_id = rm.id
  LEFT JOIN ts_request rq ON rq.id = rp.request_id
  LEFT JOIN ts_allocation a ON a.request_id = rq.id
WHERE room_id = "D.0.02"
  AND (a.status IS NULL OR a.status IN ('Pending', 'Failed', 'Declined'))
  AND (day_id=1 AND period_id=2)
```

Here is my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e1de/13

If the status is not Pending, Failed, Declined the room is ignored but it could be free for other period or days but not booked - if it is not booked then it is not allocated - this means that the day_id and period_id will not exist but the room will still be free to book.

It would seem that I would need to retype my SQL query. Any advice on how to?

Comment: Except status clause that is not correct, my understanding is desired result set should return 1 record ie. using clause <<(day_id=1 AND period_id=2)>> both conditions has to be true, but "D.0.02 allocated for day 1 period 1", so i think clause should be <<AND (rq.day_id = 1 AND rq.period_id IN (1,2))>>.  You should clarify / post the expected/ desired result set like, for specific room get allocated and / or requested in specific day / period. Hope this helps at least to clarify what you want from this query.

Comment: Can you please show me an example on SQLFiddle

Comment: Just edited you sample - but please note that i ignored the status clause is not clear to me. Please edit as needed http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e1de/140

Comment: Sorry let me explain clearly - the day_id and period_id tell you the time when the booking is made and the status tells you the condition of the allocation.

Comment: If the status is not Pending, Failed, Declined the room is ignored but it could be free for other period or days but not booked - if it is not booked then it is not allocated - this means that the day_id and period_id will not exist but the room will still be free to book

Comment: ok - add the details in post

Comment: I've added this. Any suggestion on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Count()` **always** returns a number even when no rows match.
In your case, no rows match, so count() returns `0`.

**Edit:**

Your select counts the number of bookings. 0 means that it is unbooked.

If you want to return 1 when it is unbooked you need to reverse it:

```
SELECT 1 - COUNT(DISTINCT rm.Id) 
FROM ts_room rm LEFT JOIN ts_roompref rp ON rp.room_id = rm.id
  LEFT JOIN ts_request rq ON rq.id = rp.request_id
  LEFT JOIN ts_allocation a ON a.request_id = rq.id
WHERE room_id = "D.0.02"
  AND a.status = 'Allocated'
       AND day_id=1 AND period_id=2
```

Note that if you make a wider search, for instance all periods in a day, you need to change the `1` to the number of periods (`9`) to return the number of free slots.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase my SQL but have been battling at it for the past hour. Any way I can change this so that it recognises that if D.0.02 is booked for day 1 period 1 then it should count 0 but it should count 1 for period 2 if it hasn't been booked

Comment: I've tested it here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8851c/12. Still seems to be returning 1 for D.0.02 even though it is booked for day 1 period 1.

Comment: The possible periods are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and the possible days are 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: You say that `0` is not what you expected, and neither is `1`. What do you expect?

Comment: Lindback This SQL is close to what I want to achieve but it doesn't seem to take into account the fact that if allocation status is either Pending, Failed or Declined then the room is available. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e1de/187

Comment: So if I don't want to return count and return all data I would do this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09ba2/5 > seems to be returning an error

Answer (score 0):

The status of the room `D.0.02`  is `"Allocated"`.

`a.status IN ('Pending', 'Failed', 'Declined')` = false

`a.status IS NULL` = false

The result of statement `WHERE` becomes `false`.

No rooms are found.

Comment: Yes I understand that but it is allocated for day 1 period 1 only. If it hasn't been allocated for day 1 period 2 then it should return as true but I have no idea how to implement this at the moment. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your dayId and period_id are varchar and you are comparing it as numeric

Update the last line of your query and also add records for that day_id and period_id so that you can get result.

```
AND (day_id like "1" AND period_id like "2")
```

Updated

```
 select 1- count(distinct rp.Id) from 
ts_roompref rp, ts_request rq, ts_allocation ta
where rp.room_id= "D.0.02" AND rq.id = rp.request_id and
ta.request_id = rq.id AND ta.status not in ("Pending", "Declined", "Failed")
AND day_id like "1" AND period_id like "5";
```

Check 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e1de/187

Hope this helps

Comment: In some cases day_id and period_id aren't available because they are only added if a room is requested. I wanted to factor this logic into my search as well. So it looks for where it doesn't exist as well and looks through where it exists - and where it exists it checks the allocation status Could you also please also reupload your SQL fiddle

Comment: It seems to be working fine but I've checked period 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and day 1,2,3,4,5 (possible values) but it still returns 0

Comment: There are no records for other period that you are mentioning and there is end condition which becomes every time you enter those records. There are only 2 records in your request table having in (1,5) and (1,2) combination. Once if i add records you will get results.

Comment: Yes but I want it to factor in these records even if they don't exist. For instance if you book a hotel room for day 1, period 3 then it is automatically entered into the system. It is pending - so it is still available for others to see until it is Allocated. The same room may not be free on day 1, period 4 and the records may not exist as a result. It should also come up when a search is made

Comment: What about checking for "Pending, Declined, Failed , Allocated" if day id and period id is found? If anything else then Pending, Declined, Failed is found then it means the room cannot be booked